# Overview of log4j configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I am rather confused by  how to configure Log4j    I have picked up following snippets, but something written that pulls these concepts together would be useful.

- Log4j looks for properties/xml files in the CLASSPATH
- You can supply
  your own file using PropertyConfigurator.configure(filename) - what
  if you call this twice.  Are the files effectively merged or is only
  the last one used.
- You can supply an explicit file using -D on the
  command line

I want to be able to

- Supply a basic config file that remains  static
- Allow an individual developer to add an additional file with extra options without having ot exit this  main file.

Comment: Have you looked at the [tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)?

Comment: Do not know if Log4j reads more configurations, but maybe this method can help you implement it: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#doConfigure%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository%29)

> The existing configuration is not cleared nor reset.

`log4j` itself stops at the first log4j.properties it find.

So when you call `configure`, my guess is:

- if some configuration is already done then the current will be merged.
- if configuration has not been done then log4j will not attempt to read any other log4j.properties

Your best best is to probably call `configure` with global and then with developer-specific file. But this should be easy to test.